Why would a snake try to swallow itself?
On Youtube, there is a video where a veterinarian has to take care of a snake who swallowed its tail, like trying to swallow itself.
The man didn't seem surprised about this behaviour.
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=puKevC5boFg
I guess it's a pathologic behaviour, but do you know what can be the causes ?

I'd guess more of a reflexive behaviour than pathologic.

Read this: https://www.petmd.com/reptile/conditions/behavioral/ouroboros-snake-bites-its-own-tail

Towards the end, when snakes are ill, they will bite themselves ... I’ve seen rattle snakes go into convolutions and bite their own bodies.

Another explanation could be due to stress. Cramped enclosures that restrict movement lead the snake to become confused and unable to distinguish its tail from prey.

When kept in small containment, the snake is unable to stretch out fully and may think that its tail is that of another snake.

